# How can I run the code in VS Code using Code Runner extension without selecting the code?

Tags: vscode-extensions, coderunner

I have just started my journey in programming. I have a problem in VS Code using .run "Code Runner" extension. I only can run code if I select it [here is a screen shot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj5ar.png) otherwise it doesn't work as it only gives me the last runned code which i ran as selected[here is the previous code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGUZc.png).

Comment: It looks like the file has not been saved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. when I save the file, it works perfectly.

Comment: Light speed sir. This is only the beginning!